# Why doesn't the animation-name property work in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, css-animations

Why doesn't the `animation-name?` property seem to work in React Native?
I am getting this error:
`Invariant Violation: "animationName" is not a valid style property.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-native does not work with the DOM (as normal web-browsers do), but has their own components for doing certain things, for example animations.

You can use `Animated` `LayoutAnimation` to do this